# Subtract time from time with php

Tags: php

Hi i have a database which has the pages a visitor has viewed and the time which they landed on that page.  what i am trying to do is take the time the visitor views page A then the time the visitor views page b and then subtract A from B to get how long the visitor stayed on that page for.

at the moment, in my example the difference is two seconds but the result is returned as zero, is this because 2 seconds is  a low number that the result is rounded up?

Here is my code.

```
$a = new DateTime('09:14:52');
$b = new DateTime('09:14:54');
$interval = $a->diff($b);

echo $interval->format("%H");
```

Thanks

Comment: `strtotime() - strtotime()` ?

Comment: `%H` stands for hours, so 0 looks like the expected result to me? http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = strtotime('09:14:52');
$b = strtotime('09:14:54');
$interval = $b-$a;

echo $interval. " Seconds";
?>
```

And your own code is correct too, just that format label is for an `HOUR` not for a `SECOND`. Try

```
<?php

$a = new DateTime('09:14:52');
$b = new DateTime('09:14:54');
$interval = $a->diff($b);

echo $interval->format("%s");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using strtotime directly on dates?

```
echo  strtotime('09:14:54') - strtotime('09:14:52') . ' Seconds';
```

this will output

```
2 Seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');// you should define a default time zone
$a = new DateTime('09:14:52');
$b = new DateTime('09:14:54');
$interval = $a->diff($b);

echo $interval->format("%s");
```